# Extracting information from multiple resumes all in PDF format

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, nlp, pypdf

I have a data set with a column which has google drive link for resumes, I have 5000 rows so there are 5000 links , I am trying to extract information like years of experience and salary from these resumes in 2 separate columns. so far I've seen so many examples mentioned here on SO.

For example: the code mentioned below can only read the data from one file , how do I replicate this to multiple rows ?

Please help me with this , else I will have to manually go through 500 resumes and fill in the data

Hoping that I'll get a solution for this painful problem that I have.

```
pdf_file = open('sample.pdf', 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
page_content = page.extractText()
print page_content.encode('utf-8')

#to extract salary , experience using regular expressions
import re

prog = re.compile("\s*(Name|name|nick).*")
result = prog.match("Name: Bob Exampleson")

if result:
    print result.group(0)

result = prog.match("University: MIT")

if result:
    print result.group(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop. Basically you put your main code into a function (easier to read) and create a list of filenames. Then you iterate over this list, using the values from the list as argument for your function:

Note: I didn't check your scraping code, just showing how to loop. There are also way more efficient ways to do this, but I'm assuming you're somewhat of a Python beginner so lets keep it simple to start with.

```python
# add your imports to the top
import re

# create a list of your filenames
files_list = ['a.pdf', 'b.pdf', 'c.pdf']
for filename in files_list:  # iterate over the list
    get_data(filename)


# put the rest in a function for readability
def get_data(filename):
    pdf_file = open(filename, 'rb')
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
    page_content = page.extractText()
    print page_content.encode('utf-8')

    prog = re.compile("\s*(Name|name|nick).*")
    result = prog.match("Name: Bob Exampleson")

    if result:
        print result.group(0)

    result = prog.match("University: MIT")

    if result:
        print result.group(0)
```

So now your next question might be, how do I create this list with 5000 filenames? This depends on what the files are called and where they are stored. If they are sequential, you could to something like:

```python
files_list = []  # empty list
num_files = 5000  # total number of files
for i in range(1, num_files+1):
    files_list.append(f'myfile-{i}.pdf')
```

This will create a list with 'myfile-1.pdf', 'myfile-2.pdf', etc.

Hopefully this is enough to get you started.

You can also use `return` in your function to create a new list with all of the output which you can use later on, instead of printing the output as you go:

```python
output = []

def doSomething(i):
    return i * 2

for i in range(1, 100):
    output.append(doSomething(i))

# output is now a list with values like:
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, ...]
```